# How to defer foreach variable expansion in makefile prerequisites?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, recipe

I have the following makefile that creates a `config.json` file from terraform output and then parses that config.json file and creates a makefile list variable, I then loop over that list and trigger targets accordingly. The targets copies the directories from `output/%/csv` to `current/%/csv` by looping over the list `abc xyz`

```
CONFIG = config.json
tf:
    terraform output -json > $(CONFIG)

config_file: tf
    $(eval obj := $(shell jq -c '.objects.value[]' $(CONFIG)))

output/%/csv : current/%/csv
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -r $< $@

apply: $(foreach X, $(obj), output/$X/csv)
```

The above makefile gives an empty output. I expected this result since the prerequisites are expanded immediately and have empty value, to resolve this I added `.SECONDEXPANSION:` to have the prerequisites expanded in the deferred phase. But then got an error `No rule to make target output//csv', needed by apply'.  Stop.` This means the variables are still assigned an empty value.

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
CONFIG = config.json
tf:
    terraform output -json > $(CONFIG)

config_file: tf
    $(eval obj := $(shell jq -c '.objects.value[]' $(CONFIG)))

output/%/csv : current/%/csv
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -r $< $@

apply: $(foreach $X, $$(obj), output/$$(X)/csv)
```

Is there something that I am missing here or is there any better way to do this?

Comment: There is nothing assigning `years` or `X` in the code you show. We cannot help with what we don't see. Visit maybe the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and especially [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: oops yeah that was typo. Updated the question

Comment: I explained this in the previous question you asked.  Nothing in your makefile depends on the target `config_file` and so make has no reason to build that target.  Since it doesn't need to build the target, it won't run the recipe.  Since it doesn't run the recipe, your variable `obj` will never be set.  If you want to do it this way, then two things must be true: first, _every_ target whose recipe depends on the value of `obj` must list `config_file` as a prerequisite.  And second, `config_file` can never be considered up-to-date since then make won't try to build it.

Comment: However, `.SECONDEXPANSION` is not sufficient here.  You need `obj` set BEFORE make needs to expand the prerequisites of `apply`.  That means just listing `config_file` as a prerequisite of `apply` won't help since of course make can't create prerequisites until after it's expanded them.  As Renaud says, 99.9999% of the time when you see an `eval` in a recipe, you're going down the wrong path.  As I mentioned in your previous question the best way forward is to have your rule that parses `config.json` generate a makefile, then `include` that makefile and let make rebuild it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to set the `obj` make variable in a recipe with `eval`. In almost all examples I saw where `eval` or `shell` make functions were used in a recipe it was an error.

What about the following?

```
OBJ     := $(shell terraform output -json | jq -c '.objects.value[]')
TARGETS := $(patsubst %,output/%/csv,$(OBJ))

output/%/csv : current/%/csv
    mkdir -p $(@D)
    cp -r $< $@

.PHONY: apply
apply: $(TARGETS)
```